# PDO fetch outputing bool(false)

Tags: php, try-catch

when i am fetching a database table from PDO fetch then it shows bool(false)

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM replies WHERE comment_id = :comment_id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':comment_id' => $postcomment['id']));
    $repl = $stmt->fetch(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
var_dump($repl); ?>
```

Comment: Just because a select query succeeds doesn't mean it returns rows.  Fetch will return false if there aren't any rows or if you've reached the end of the resultset.

Comment: `print_r($db->errorInfo());` Same with `$stmt`.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be expecting an exception when the query fails. That only happens AFAIK when you set the appropriate attribute on the PDO object (either `PDOStatement` or `PDO`, see [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://php.net/pdo.setattribute)):

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

after setting this, all fetch calls (and similar) will throw an exception on error instead of returning some `false` return value. Then, the try-catch block actually provides some benefits.

Remark: The `setAttribute` stuff can also be done in the PDO constructor (see [`PDO::__construct`](http://php.net/pdo.construct%20pdo::__construct))